# Adding custom attribute in all spring integration component

Tags: spring-integration

I need to add custom attribute to all spring integration component for example - need to add 'description' attribute to all inbound and outbound gateway.

Once we are able to add the custom attribute, I need to log the newly added attribute - 'description'.

Can you please suggest the approach for this.

Thanks

Comment: I believe this is somehow related to your: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499106/spring-integration-how-to-intercept-all-spring-integration-component-and-fetch. Since all the Spring Integration components are just objects based on some Java classes, it is really impossible to add anything new to those classes. Therefore your task is just impossible as long as Java doesn't allow to add new properties to already compiled classes.

Comment: Thanks Artem! Just a thought to use "id" attribute to enter my short description something like id="id1_calling_X_Service". This is because I have an access to this attribute with the help of message history and currently we are not using id attribute anywhere. But just wanted to know that will it going to have any impact in future in terms of "id" attribute being used internally for some other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I've explained you how it isn't going to be possible because if Java nature. Now let's try to imagine what we could do on the matter. You can register some additional support beans in the application context and have their relationship to the integration components. For example through some `id` pattern or key-value store like simple `HashMap`. So, this way you always will be able to extract that additional information whenever you get access to the original component: or rely on its `id` or call the map registry.